# Can I store a fast-lookup index to a tar file using python's tarfile package?

Tags: python, tar

I have a large tar archive and am using python (3.6+) and the `tarfile` package.

If I use `tar_info = tarfile.getmember(filename)` I can then call `tarfile.extract(tar_info)`, however the call to `extract` is slow, appearing to scan the file, taking many minutes on a large archive.

I see that the `tar_info` object has an offset in it, so it seems like this should be a quick seek and read operation.

I'm wondering if there is a way to store an index into the tar file such that *it is* a quick seek and read operation to extract any specific file, given that I have the necessary information indexed outside the tar file.

Comment: Is the tar file compressed?  If yes, then it's doubtful having the offset is helpful as it has to decompress enough to reach the desired location and then fetch the data.  Zip is a better format if you need quick, single file extraction.

Comment: This is a useful answer too: https://superuser.com/a/655802

Comment: Yes, working with compressed archives, I'll take the zip suggestion under advisement, that might indeed be a better approach than fighting something that doesn't want to yield. I think that superuser question answers this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This superuser.com question answers it, by John Szakmeister in comments, thanks!

https://superuser.com/questions/655739/extract-single-file-from-huge-tgz-file/655802#655802

Short answer: if you enable compression it's streamed across the tar archive, not per-file, so the answer is no.